# sqlite3.exe: How to stop a long-running SQL statement

Tags: windows, sqlite

How do I stop a long-running SQL statement in sqlite3.exe running on Windows?

The documentation at http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html states the following

> You can terminate the sqlite3 program by typing your systems
>   End-Of-File character (usually a Control-D). Use the interrupt
>   character (usually a Control-C) to stop a long-running SQL statement.

But on Windows Control-D does nothing and Control-C terminates the sqlite3 program.

I've also tried Break (i.e. Control-Pause) which does the same as Control-C

Any ideas?

Comment: Technically Ctrl+C *did* stop the query, then.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have time to check out your patch yet, but your analysis looks solid and I definitely believe it will solve my problem. If you would raise it as a bug with the SQLite maintainers that would be great. Marking your answer as accepted and awarding the bounty now :)

Comment: Thanks, I've sent a message to the SQLite mailing list, and updated the answer below with an improved patch that I sent them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug on Windows only.

Looking at the code in the [C source code as an amalgamation, version 3.8.8.3.](http://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-amalgamation-3080803.zip) from the SQLite [download page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), I see that in `shell.c`, there is a handler for `SIGINT` (corresponding to Control-C on Windows) registered if `SIGINT` is defined:

```
#ifdef SIGINT
  signal(SIGINT, interrupt_handler);
#endif
```

`SIGINT` is defined in `signal.h`, but it has been deliberately excluded on Windows:

```
#if !defined(_WIN32) && !defined(WIN32)
# include <signal.h>
# if !defined(__RTP__) && !defined(_WRS_KERNEL)
#  include <pwd.h>
# endif
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
#endif
```

Including `signal.h` causes the signal handler to be registered, and I do get the interruption (without process termination!) to a long-running SQL command with Control-C as expected.

This does not work reliably for subsequent Control-C events though (e.g. if you want to interrupt a second long-running command in your session), and `signal(SIGINT,...)` is [documented as unsupported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx) for Win32 applications on MSDN.

Using the Windows-specific [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `signal(SIGINT,...)` to register an interrupt handler works reliably for subsequent Control-C events.

Here is a diff for `shell.c` for the source version mentioned using `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`:

```
757c757
< #ifdef SIGINT
---
> #if defined(SIGINT) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32)
766a767,782
> 
> #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32)
> /*
> ** Windows event handler
> */
> BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD dwType){ 
>   switch( dwType ){
>     case CTRL_C_EVENT: 
>       interrupt_handler(0);
>       return TRUE;
>  
>     default: 
>       return FALSE; 
>   } 
> }
> #endif
4207a4224,4225
> #elif defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
>   SetConsoleCtrlHandler(CtrlHandler, TRUE);
```

The shell can easily be built by adding all the source files in that amalgamation to a Visual Studio C++ console project (there are no external dependencies besides the standard/system headers needed to build).

I've sent a message to the SQLite users mailing list to notify them of the bug.